# (int) is not working?

Tags: android, type-conversion

I want to convert double value of 1.09478878083135368E7 to int.
so I use

> int formatted = (int)1.09478878083135368E7;

Then I send this value to another activity as a string by using

> final string distance = String.valueOf(formatted);

I'm expecting to see "1" as a result but what I'm getting is 10947878.
Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1.09478878083135368E7` .. Notice the E7, that's [(scientific) E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for 'move the period E points right'.

So in your case; `1.09478878083135368E7` becomes `10947887.8083135368`, so converting to an int gives us 10947887 (you have 10947878 which might have been a typo?)

Comment: to add, if you want the integer value, user `Math.round`

Comment: why ? using Math.round also get 10947878

Comment: `Math.Round` might actually get you +1 in this case because of the `.8`; so the number on a `Math.Round` would be `10947888` (maybe not what you want in this case?)

Comment: thanks a lot textechhelp and thepoosh . I finally use Math.round :)